# Table gets broken when using map function inside

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
<tbody className="PMRFYColor">           
  <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong><i>{this.state.families[i].label}</i></strong></td></tr>
    {this.state.types && (
        <div>
            {this.state.types
                .map(types => (
                    <div>
                        <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>{types.typename}</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType(types.typename, this.state.families[i].familyKey)}
                        {/* <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>DELIVER</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType("Deliver", this.state.families[i].familyKey)}
                        <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>SUSTAIN</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType("Sustain", this.state.families[i].familyKey)} */}
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    )}
    <tr><td colSpan={colSpanForWeight}><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td colSpan="2" align="right" style={{ paddingRight: "2%" }}><strong>{this.getTotalWeight(this.state.families[i].familyKey)}</strong></td></tr>
    <tr hidden={typekey === 'Target' ? true : false}><td colSpan={colSpanForWeight}
        className="td-pass"><strong>Total Passing/On Track</strong></td>
        <td colSpan="2" className="td-pass" align="right" style={{ paddingRight: "2%" }}><strong>{this.getPassPercentage(this.state.families[i].familyKey)}</strong></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

When I dont use the mapping function the table displays correctly, however, when I use map the table gets broken, as you can see in the next image.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why are you putting `<div>` elements in your table structure?  That's likely to throw off the structure at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mapping next to a `tr` element, but you're producing a `div` element and then mapping inside of it to more `div` elements with `tr` elements inside.

That structure will result in:

```html
<tbody ...>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <div>  <------- first div wrapper
    <div>  <------- one extra div per mapped element
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
    </div>
    <div>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
    </div>
    <div>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  <tr><td ...>...</td></tr>
  <tr><td ...>...</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

That's not a valid table structure, as you can't have a `div` as a direct child of `tbody`. You probably want to use React.Fragment instead:

```
<tbody className="PMRFYColor">           
  <tr><td colSpan="9">..../td></tr>
    {this.state.types && (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.state.types
                .map(types => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>{types.typename}</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType(types.typename, this.state.families[i].familyKey)}
                        {/* <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>DELIVER</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType("Deliver", this.state.families[i].familyKey)}
                        <tr><td colSpan="9"><strong>SUSTAIN</strong></td></tr>
                        {this.getKPIDataForEachType("Sustain", this.state.families[i].familyKey)} */}
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
    <tr><td colSpan={colSpanForWeight}><strong>Total</strong></td>
```

`React.Fragment` won't render an element, but its children directly. So, you'll produce:

```html
<tbody ...>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>

  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr> <---- no wrapping per mapped element
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>

  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>

  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>
  <tr><td colSpan="9">...</td></tr>

  <tr><td ...>...</td></tr>
  <tr><td ...>...</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

---

I'm assuming you'll eventually uncomment those DELIVER/SUSTAIN bits. If you're going to remove them, you can remove the `React.Fragment` from within the mapping function, and just return the only `tr` you have left.

Finally, you can use the shorthand fragment syntax, that is: `<>content here</>` but make sure you have it enabled in your transpiler.

Comment: You are totally correct! I didn't know the tag React.Fragment exists. That is very helpful. Thank you for the good explanation!